# Maven goal to delete certain files without necessarily invoking clean?

Tags: maven

I have a Java-Maven project wherein I have a directory in my project's root directory that I need to delete every once one a while, lets call it logs directory. It contains mostly logs and other temporarily generated files. I was wondering if it's possible to utilize the clean plugin for this. It doesn't seem so since reading about it indicates it can only be leveraged for deleting additional artifacts when performing a clean but I might not necessarily want my target directory deleted every time I need to delete my logs directory. So, is this possible via Maven? If so, how? Thank you.

Comment: Temporary files etc. and generated files should be put into `target` folder that makes life easier...cause everything else is usually under version control...

Answer (score 1):

The [`maven-clean-plugin` tutorial](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html)  is a useful guide to follow for such implementation. Primarily, you need to configure the plugin to include the directory explicitly as:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <filesets>
        <fileset>
          <directory>${basedir}/src/main/logs</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
          </includes>
          <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
        </fileset>
      </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

where the directory path should be the path to your logs folder(just for e.g.) and is relative to your module.